# Email sent via CiviRules removes unsubscribe token from email template

Tags: civimail, civirules

I tested an email template via CiviMail and the unsubscribe link works and the HTML shows it. In the source it comes up as

```
<a href="{action.optOutUrl}" style="text-decoration: none; color:
#fffffe;" target="_blank">Unsubscribe here.</a>
```

But if the same email template is triggered & sent via CiviRules (you can choose the template along with rules and conditions on how to trigger it), the tag shown above gets stripped out leaving just the text "Unsubscribe here" which has no link - just text! So no one can actually unsub.

Does anyone know how to deal with this? Is there a way to just use the link without using the token? I went through the CiviCRM documentation and didn't find what I was looking for :(

I tried the different versions of the tokens related to unsubscribe/opt out but no joy.

Cheers

Comment: I have also added your problem on the CiviRules GitHub repo: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/issues/163

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the `{action.optOutUrl}` token is that generates a url which is linked to a send mass mailing.

When CiviRules sends an e-mail it is not a mass mailing but an inidvidual one. Send to one specific contact at the time.

I could understand that you want some sort of link to a profile/optout page. One way to do that is probably create a profile page and link to that page from within the e-mail you send from CiviRules.

Did you solve the issue yourself? If so how?

Comment: I am using GDPR module & civirules to receive subscription/unsubscribe. What I have noticed is missing an option in civirules - "privacy prefrerence" - NO BULK MAIL. I think that would solve the issue.